# What kind of literary device is this?

Tags: literary-device

The usage of the word "mind" in the following sentence:

> King Solomon was the greatest mind that ever lived.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[*Synecdoche*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synecdoche) is a figure of speech using a part for the whole, the whole for the part, general for specific, or specific for general.

> *Brass* can be all the brass instruments in the orchestra or top military officers.
>
> *Our daily bread* in the Lord's Prayer means all the necessities of life.
>
> Don't use cash, pay with *plastic*, i.e. a plastic credit card.

Using *mind* for *thinker* or *person of great wisdom* is a classic example.

Comment: "Pay with plastic" is metonymy.

Comment: The article cited gives a list of examples of "material for thing made from it." Synecdoche goes beyond pars pro toto/totum pro parte.

Comment: I am certain it is metonymy.

Answer (score 1):

Allusion is another literary device in the sentence *King Solomon was the greatest mind that ever lived*

> [Allusion](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/allusion):  an expression designed to call something to mind without mentioning it explicitly; an indirect or passing reference.

In the sentence, the allusion is to King Solomon and his mind, as it is not explicitly describing what he or his mind have done to be the greatest to ever live, however it is implied.

> [Allusion](https://literarydevices.net/allusion/) is a brief and indirect reference to a person, place, thing or idea of historical, cultural, literary or political significance. It does not describe in detail the person or thing to which it refers. It is just a passing comment and the writer expects the reader to possess enough knowledge to spot the allusion and grasp its importance in a text.